# How to use a PDF map with plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, gis

I want the parameter that allows me to update the layout with a PDF map instead of an open-street-map for `plotly.express.scatter_mapbox`.

I've searched through the documentation of Plotly, and searched online but I couldn't find the answer.

Line within comments below is the one that I want to change.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

us_cities = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/us-cities-top-1k.csv")
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(us_cities, lat="lat", lon="lon", hover_name="City", hover_data=["State", "Population"],
                        color_discrete_sequence=["fuchsia"], zoom=3, height=600)
# --------------------------------------------------
# Change this line to include PDF map instead of "open-street-map"
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
# ---------------------------------------------------
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Comment: not sure what a PDF map is, do you know of an example?

Comment: By PDF map I mean: a map that is saved as a .pdf file. This is opposed to a more typical map that would be saved with a .shp/.sql.

Answer (score 0):

To save an image to a pdf file you can use:

```
fig.write_image("fig1.pdf")
```

...more info can be found at the plotly help page [Static Image Export in Python](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/).

For reference, the `mapbox_style` argument will not accept `PDF` as an input, see [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter_mapbox.html) (and below) for acceptable inputs.

> **mapbox_style** (str (default 'basic', needs Mapbox API token)) –
> Identifier of base map style, some of which require a Mapbox API token
> to be set using plotly.express.set_mapbox_access_token(). Allowed
> values which do not require a Mapbox API token are 'open-street-map',
> 'white-bg', 'carto-positron', 'carto-darkmatter', 'stamen- terrain',
> 'stamen-toner', 'stamen-watercolor'. Allowed values which do require a
> Mapbox API token are 'basic', 'streets', 'outdoors', 'light', 'dark',
> 'satellite', 'satellite- streets'.